# using IIS with self signed cert created using New-SelfSignedCertificate works one local site but not another

Tags: ssl, iis, owin

I've created a local ssl cert for the url *.test.com

I have two sites 
ap1.test.com and api2.test.com that are both configured with local host names and are both set up on 127.0.0.1 in my host file.
Both are set up to use the same cert in IIS

One works correctly in Chrome and the other has a 
"Your connection is not private error"
 NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

I have additional local mvc style websites all using the same cert.

Is there anything about a .NET WebAPI2 project using OWIN that could cause a cert to fail?

Thank you

Comment: is this a self signed cert? those always generate a warning

Comment: What version of Chrome?

Comment: d'oh I just realized had a typo in my domain name. The wildcard doesn't work if the string doesn't match :/